# My regex does not match numbers

Tags: javascript, regex

I am new at making regular expressions, and so this might just be a stupid oversight, but my regex (that aims to match URL's) is not working. My goal was to have it match any urls like:

```
http://www.somewhere.com
somewhere.com
https://ww3.some_where-hi.com
www.goop.go/herp/derp.lol
```

The regex i built is below, however, it does not match a URL like `http://t.co/GZhtBh6c`, it stops matching at the number 6 (As determined by [www.regexpal.com](http://www.regexpal.com)).

```
((http|https)://)?([a-z0-9]+\.)?[a-z0-9\-_]+.[a-z]+(/[a-z0-9\-_]*)*([a-z0-9\-_]*\.[a-z]+){0,1}
```

Can anyone tell me why this is not working? Also, I'm sure this is not the best solution. If you have a more elegant regex for this, I would love to see it.

P.S. This regex will be used with javascript.

Comment: Note that your regex would also miss `HTTP://WWW.GOOGLE.COM`, for example.

Comment: oh, i would be using case insensitive mode, but thanks

Comment: In general, don't use regexes to match URLs - there are many better ways of doing that. If this is a pedagogical exercise to play with regexes, then that's fine, but don't do it in any "production" code.

Comment: People who are answering the question are not understanding the porblem. My regex works on the examples, but not on http://t.co/GZhtBh6c, where it does not match the 6.

Comment: @PhilipKendall I am interested to know of these other ways. This is purely for fun, but I don't know how to do this another way.

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve - I'm interested in the general problem, rather than the specific problem with your regex?

Comment: @PhilipKendall I am taking plaintext urls that I get from twitter API and turning them into links when I display them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Validate if a string holds a URL as specified in RFC 3986.  Both absolute and relative URLs are supported.

This matches your provide sample and more. It also lets you extract the different parts of the url

```
^
(# Scheme
 [a-z][a-z0-9+\-.]*:
 (# Authority & path
  //
  ([a-z0-9\-._~%!$&'()*+,;=]+@)?              # User
  ([a-z0-9\-._~%]+                            # Named host
  |\[[a-f0-9:.]+\]                            # IPv6 host
  |\[v[a-f0-9][a-z0-9\-._~%!$&'()*+,;=:]+\])  # IPvFuture host
  (:[0-9]+)?                                  # Port
  (/[a-z0-9\-._~%!$&'()*+,;=:@]+)*/?          # Path
 |# Path without authority
  (/?[a-z0-9\-._~%!$&'()*+,;=:@]+(/[a-z0-9\-._~%!$&'()*+,;=:@]+)*/?)?
 )
|# Relative URL (no scheme or authority)
 ([a-z0-9\-._~%!$&'()*+,;=@]+(/[a-z0-9\-._~%!$&'()*+,;=:@]+)*/?  # Relative path
 |(/[a-z0-9\-._~%!$&'()*+,;=:@]+)+/?)                            # Absolute path
)
# Query
(\?[a-z0-9\-._~%!$&'()*+,;=:@/?]*)?
# Fragment
(\#[a-z0-9\-._~%!$&'()*+,;=:@/?]*)?
$
```

In javascript this becomes

```
if (/^([a-z][a-z0-9+\-.]*:(\/\/([a-z0-9\-._~%!$&'()*+,;=]+@)?([a-z0-9\-._~%]+|\[[a-f0-9:.]+\]|\[v[a-f0-9][a-z0-9\-._~%!$&'()*+,;=:]+\])(:[0-9]+)?(\/[a-z0-9\-._~%!$&'()*+,;=:@]+)*\/?|(\/?[a-z0-9\-._~%!$&'()*+,;=:@]+(\/[a-z0-9\-._~%!$&'()*+,;=:@]+)*\/?)?)|([a-z0-9\-._~%!$&'()*+,;=@]+(\/[a-z0-9\-._~%!$&'()*+,;=:@]+)*\/?|(\/[a-z0-9\-._~%!$&'()*+,;=:@]+)+\/?))(\?[a-z0-9\-._~%!$&'()*+,;=:@\/?]*)?(#[a-z0-9\-._~%!$&'()*+,;=:@\/?]*)?$/im.test(subject)) {
    // Successful match
} else {
    // Match attempt failed
}
```

Answer (score -1):

use a `[A-z]` instead of `[a-z]`
your little `a-z` is only matching lowercase letters.

Comment: I would be in case insensitive mode.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question which is related to numbers, but anyway, is `[A-z]` a valid shortcut for `[A-Za-z]`? Interesting..

Comment: `[A-z]` is **not** the same as `[A-Za-z]`; it includes several punctuation characters in addition to the letters.